# resizeMode not working in React Native Android

Tags: react-native

**Update 2021**

resizeMode not working while given as a style prop to Image in RN Android

<s>borderRadius works as expected in iOS but not working as expected in Android. I tried to wrap the `Image` in a View and gave `borderRadius` and `overFlow: 'hidden'`</s>

```
  <View style={styles.userImageContainer}>
    <Image source={require('../../assets/images/user1.png')}
      style={styles.userImage}
    />
  </View>
```

StyleSheet

const imageSize = 40;

```
  userImageContainer: {
    height: imageSize,
    width: imageSize,
    borderWidth: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    borderRadius: imageSize/2,
    overflow: 'hidden'
  },
  userImage: {
    height: imageSize,
    width: imageSize,
    borderRadius: imageSize/2,
    padding: 5,
    resizeMode: 'contain'
  },
```

End result

[image]

I am using RN <s>0.42.2</s> 0.66.3

Comment: What happens if you don't use the const and just use the value directly?

Comment: Hi, makes no difference when given values directly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Applying `borderRadius` and `resizeMode` as props instead as a style attribute will fix the borderRadius issue in Android

```
<Image
  source={{uri: 'path'}}
  style={styles.image}
  resizeMode="cover"
  borderRadius={value}
/>
```

<s>For those who are facing this issue, its a known issue with react-native android. As of now there is no fix for it.</s>

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.26/docs/known-issues.html#the-overflow-style-property-defaults-to-hidden-and-cannot-be-changed-on-android